# I need a clear explanation of these nested For Loops

Tags: javascript

```
let n = 5;

for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        console.log(i, j);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 0
2 0
2 1
3 0
3 1
3 2
4 0
4 1
4 2
4 3
5 0
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 4
```

If I'm not mistaken the outer loop will increment once the inner loop finishes executing, but what I cannot understand is why `j` prints 0 at some points. Don't initialized expressions get redefined when incremented?

Comment: always  when the inner loop is finished and go out in the outer loop again then the j in the inner one will re-initialised with 1 again

Comment: When `i` is larger than zero, `j` might be smaller and can be zero. The condition `j<i` matches and the console.log command is executed.

Comment: Go through it step by step with pen and paper…

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=let%20n%20%3D%205%3B%0A%0Afor%20%28let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%20n%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28let%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20i%3B%20j%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28i,%20j%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Answer (score 2):

Every iteration of the Outer loop evaluates the entire inner loop from scratch (including initializing j to start at zero).

- First Outer loop iteration:

  - i is set to 0.
  - First Inner loop iteration:

    - j is set to 0.
    - The inner loop condition j < i is False since they are both zero.
    - The inner loop body does not run.
- Second Outer loop iteration:

  - i increments to 1.
  - First Inner loop iteration within second outer loop iteration:

    - j is set to 0.
    - (i=1,j=0) is logged to console
  - First Inner loop iteration within second outer loop iteration:

    - j is incremented to 1, the inner loop condition is False. Inner loop does not run a second time.
- Third Outer loop iteration:

  - i increments to 2.
  - First Inner loop iteration within third outer loop iteration:

    - j is set to 0.
    - (i=2,j=0) is logged to console
  - Second Inner loop iteration within third outer loop iteration:

    - j incremented by 1
    - (i=2,j=1) is logged to console
- ... etc

Answer (score 1):

> What I cannot understand is why `j`  prints 0 at some points.

It's the same as You move the initial `j` like below.

```js
let n = 5;
let i = 0;
for ( ; i <= n; i++) {
    let j = 0; //You move the initial `j` here
    for (; j < i; j++) {
        console.log(i, j);
    }
}
```

As you can see, after inner loop finish, `i` will increase one then the next time, `j = 0`

Answer (score 0):

**1st Iteration:**

i=0. in inner loop j =0 initialize so j<i means(0<0) so condition is false , increment i counter to 1

**2nd Iteration:**

i=1 . in inner loop j=0 . check condition j<i (0<1) condition true .Program goes to console.log and print 1 for i and 0 for j. Then increment the value of j 0 to 1. then test condition j<i(1<1) .condition false so program goes to outer loop and increment the value of 1 to 2.

**3rd Iteration:**

i=2 . in inner loop j=0 . check condition j<i (0<2) condition true .Program goes to console.log and print 2 for i and 0 for j. Then increment the value of j 0 to 1. then test condition j<i(1<2) .condition true so program goes to console.log and print 2 for i and 1 for j.Then increment the value of j 1 to 2. then test condition j<i(2<2) .condition false so program goes to  outer loop and increment the value of 1 to 3.

And in this way this nested for loops works. Hope You Understand.